# get all date from selected year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some value like this :

```
from          to
2012-04-01    2013-12-31
2014-01-01    2016-08-10
2016-08-11    2016-12-28
2016-12-30    2017-12-20
2017-12-21    2018-12-11
```

How can I get all value when i select 2016 year . I want to get this :

```
from          to
2014-01-01    2016-08-10
2016-08-11    2016-12-28
2016-12-30    2017-12-20
```

Currently my sql just get the value if both from and  to in 2016

```
.... WHERE From>='2016-01-01' AND To<='2016-12-31'
```

Note: it's an example date , so please don't post answer like this :

```
...WHERE From>='2014-01-01' AND To<='2017-12-20'
```

Comment: why not just filter based on the year only.   like (pseudocode)   `WHERE From Like '2016%' OR To Like '2016%'`

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `YEAR` function:

```
SELECT from,
       to
FROM yourTable
WHERE YEAR(from) = 2016 OR
      YEAR(to)   = 2016
```

This will retain any record which has either a `from` date *or* a `to` date which lies in the 2016 calendar year.

Comment: Thank you very much . now I realize mysql have this function :))